# Facebook Login kit with iOS 13 "canOpenURL: failed for URL: “fbauth2:///”"

Tags: ios, facebook

Facebook login kit with iOS 12 works just fine, Facebook login kit with iOS 13 doesn't allow the opening of fbauth2 urls. This has been verified here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117704

and i've verified this myself by trying FB login on my iPhone 6s Plus external device with iOS 13, and with simulators running both iOS 12 and iOS 13. Every device with iOS 13 fails to open FB urls.

does anyone have a fix for this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to the current FBSDK should resolve the problem.

FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/BridgeAPI/FBSDKBridgeAPI.m was modified to support iOS 13's requirement to implement ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding in FBSDKCoreKit 5.4.  The current version is 5.8. Versions prior will no longer work.

The needed change is posted here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/6b061099f339ef0e8bde2e2c2163ef5a3c1b8340#diff-72593591275d63edfb1bfad837e4c32f

Comment: let me check this out tomorrow,Bill and then ill give you credit, thanks for your diligence, you're a good guy. good by bill